# Flutter - export csv read as gibberish in Excel

Tags: excel, flutter

I have the following code, which I use to export Unicode chars (Herbrew) to CSV, meant to be open by Excel/Google Sheets:

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
List<int> bytes = List.from(utf8.encode(csv));
// bytes.insert(0, unicodeBomCharacterRune );
return bytes;
```

If I export it to gmail, and open it in google sheets it works fine, but when I open it it with Excel it opens it as gibberish.

I'm well familiar with this issue which I solved in other ENV (php, js) by addind BOM char at the beginning of the file,
but when I do so in flutter (ie. uncomment the line `bytes.insert(0, unicodeBomCharacterRune );`) I get gibberish both in sheets and in excel.

Any idea how to over come this issue?

Comment: In general, with Excel, if you **import** (e.g using Power Query) instead of **open**, you can specify the language variation to be used (as well as other properties such as date order, text vs number, etc) that are not usually found in CSV files.  In my Power Query, I see listed three different versions of Hebrew that could be used, as well as generic UTF8.

Comment: I need the default `open` to work as is

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it:

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
List<int> bytes = List.from(utf8.encode(csv));
bytes.insert(0, 0xBF );
bytes.insert(0, 0xBB );
bytes.insert(0, 0xEF );
return bytes;
```

`The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes at the start of a text stream (0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF) that allows the reader to more reliably guess a file as being encoded in UTF-8.`

NOTE: I insert the bytes in reverse order since I add them to the top